# Вопрос по сборке front-end на gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp4

Осваиваю gulp, возник один небольшой вопрос по импорту html элементов, немного сложно сформулировать, я надеюсь, что вы поймёте о чём я.

**src** - папка с исходниками данными,

**build** - папка с итоговыми данными.

1. сервер запускается на **build**, в корне лежит файл **index.html**
2. в папке **src** (исходники) есть папка **template**, в которой я планировал держать html код статичных блоков (header, nav, footer and etc.), повторяющихся на каждой странице.
3. в **index.html** (в корне /**build**) я подключаю созданные в папке /src/template блоки таким образом:

```
// ../../../src/template/header.html
```

4. при "перезагрузке" **index.html** вышеуказанный код вставляется "**фактически**", не импортируя содержимое соответствующего файла.

**Вопрос**: подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом настроить подобный импорт?

**Код gulpfile**

```
'use strict'

var autoprefixerList = [
    'Chrome >= 45',
    'Firefox ESR',
    'Edge >= 12',
    'Explorer >= 10',
    'iOS >= 9',
    'Safari >= 9',
    'Android >= 4.4',
    'Opera >= 30'
];

var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'app/build/',
        js: 'app/build/js/',
        css: 'app/build/css/',
        img: 'app/build/img/',
        fonts: 'app/build/fonts/'
    },
    src: {
        html: 'app/src/*.html',
        js: 'app/src/js/main.js',
        style: 'app/src/css/main.scss',
        img: 'app/src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'app/src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'app/src/**/*.html',
        js: 'app/src/js/**/*.js',
        css: 'app/src/css/**/*.scss',
        img: 'app/src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'app/src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './app/build/*'
};

var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: './app/build'
    },
    notify: false
};

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webserver = require('browser-sync'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    jpegrecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

// запуск сервера
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    webserver(config);
});

// сборка html
gulp.task('html:build', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.html)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(webserver.reload({stream: true}));
});

// assembly css

gulp.task('css:build', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.style)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: autoprefixerList
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(webserver.reload({ stream: true }));
});

// assembly js
gulp.task('js:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.src.js) // получим файл main.js
    .pipe(plumber()) // для отслеживания ошибок
    .pipe(rigger()) // импортируем все указанные файлы в main.js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //инициализируем sourcemap
    .pipe(uglify()) // минимизируем js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) //  записываем sourcemap
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js)) // положим готовый файл
    .pipe(webserver.reload({ stream: true })); // перезагрузим сервер
});

// перенос шрифтов
gulp.task('fonts:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});

// обработка картинок
gulp.task('image:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.src.img) // путь с исходниками картинок
    .pipe(cache(imagemin([ // сжатие изображений
      imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
      jpegrecompress({
        progressive: true,
        max: 90,
        min: 80
      }),
      pngquant(),
      imagemin.svgo({ plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }] })
    ])))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img)); // выгрузка готовых файлов
});

// удаление каталога build 
gulp.task('clean:build', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.clean, { read: false })
    .pipe(rimraf());
});

// очистка кэша
gulp.task('cache:clear', function () {
  cache.clearAll();
});

// сборка
gulp.task('build',
  gulp.series('clean:build',
    gulp.parallel(
      'html:build',
      'css:build',
      'js:build',
      'fonts:build',
      'image:build'
    )
  )
);

// запуск задач при изменении файлов
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(path.watch.html, gulp.series('html:build'));
  gulp.watch(path.watch.css, gulp.series('css:build'));
  gulp.watch(path.watch.js, gulp.series('js:build'));
  gulp.watch(path.watch.img, gulp.series('image:build'));
  gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('fonts:build'));
});

// задача по умолчанию
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
  'build',
  gulp.parallel('webserver','watch')      
));
```

html элементы я импортирую в index.html в папке build следующим образом

```
  //= ../../../src/template/head.html
```

Честно, я плохо понимаю как это работает, я постараюсь объяснить "мое представление". Надеюсь, вы подскажете, где я ошибаюсь.

1. Сервер запускается из папки build, при этом все исходники в папке src.
2. Я запускаю в cmd команду gulp, поднимается сервер и начинается отслеживание изменения файлов. Соответственно, открывается index.html в папке build
3. В index.html, вместе header я прописываю импорт отдельного файла с необходимым кодом (как указано выше).
4. В моем понимании, в указанное место должен импортироваться код из файла head.html (хотя, как он будет импортироваться, если сервер поднят на build, а сам файл лежит в src?)

Прошу, приведите в порядок мои мысли)))

Comment: Добавьте код вашего gulp файла, и то, как вы "подключаете" ваши html блоки

Comment: обновил стартовое сообщение, спасибо)

Comment: я вижу вы используете rigger. Почему бы вам просто не использовать шаблонизаторы? Например handlebars [gulp плагин](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars). Он вам с удовольствием предкомпилирует ваш html. Да и множество других плюшек даст. p.s. вижу вы по этому гайду делали ваш gulp [гайд](https://pugofka.com/blog/technology/the-prepared-starting-package-front-end-development-on-gulp/). А js проще сконкатенировать.

Comment: Спасибо, честно, я не ориентируюсь в gulp и его плагинах, но обязательно почитаю.
буду пробовать, спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: Жумышев, гораздо проще работать с шаблонизаторами, чем с простой "вставкой" кода при помощи сборщика проекта. Шаблонизаторы работают как на стороне сервера, так и на стороне клиента(можно просто присылать клиенту в запросе html код, и при помощи шаблонизатора вставлять его в необходимый блок на сайте, без необходимости обновления страницы). Если вы начнете использовать готовые веб серверы, к примеру express.js , то там так же будете использовать шаблонизаторы.